# Device width issue with chrome mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been working on a Wordpress site and found this very strange and completely confusing issue that only happens in Chrome when below 992px width. 
In the Picture below the body and html tags "says" its width 360px. But you can clearly see its not. I took a screen shot and put it Photoshop. The width of the content is about 288px.

Device Preview in Chrome:

[image]

Why on earth is that happening? Firefox has no problems. And in the preview you can even see the menu at the top is unaffected. So why is the entire rest of my body being squished? I inspected all the classes and tried changing widths and removing classes. Nothing changed the body.
And as reference I have made sure I have this in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any clues or tips to help me understand the issue?

**EDIT**

Ok new discovery. On my android device using chrome it seems fine. But the page scrolls to the right revealing the white space you see in the picture above. And I thought the source of the issue was the Menu that you see in the top. Accounding to Chrome the width of the menu is being set to 450px. but there is no css to say that it should be 450px. When I manually change the the menu to be 360px there is still whitespace skew the whole body. The code below is from part of the menu. The other part has a width of 100%.

```
.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, 

.container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your media queries?

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: The reasons I hate wordpress begin grow... So there is media queries ALL over the place. I dont even know where to begin to show you. And how can I provide a fiddle for a whole wordpress site?

Comment: Also check my Edit I added